# node_modules are not creating after deployment succeeded when i run from Gitlab-Ci.yml to deploy on azure app service

Tags: node-modules

Hi team i am trying to deploy on azure app service through Gitlab-ci.yml , but node_modules are not getting generated below one is the yaml file if some one help that will be great please ..
include:
# Injects TMO Global Shared
- project: 'tmobile/templates'
file: '/gitlab-ci/.tmo.global.common.gitlab-ci.yml'

```
# Inject NPM build & publish capability
- project: 'tmobile/templates'
  file: '/gitlab-ci/.tmo.function.npm.gitlab-ci.yml'

# Relic Vault
- project: 'tmobile/templates'
  file: '/gitlab-ci/.tmo.function.relic.lictor.gitlab-ci.yml'

# Injects Azure deploy template
- project: 'tmobile/templates'
  file: '/gitlab-ci/.tmo.function.azure-deploy.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

stages:
- tmo
- install
- cache
- test
- build_dev
- package
- push
- deploy

variables:
ALLOW_SONAR_FAILURE: "true"
SONAR_ANALYSIS_MODE: "publish"
AZURE_RESOURCE_TYPE: "azure_webapp"
BUILD_NUMBER: "${CI_PIPELINE_IID}-RELEASE"
APP_TYPE: "zip"
NODE_VERSION: "16.19.0"
APP_VERSION: "0.1.0"
BUILD_ARTIFACTS: "node_modules/*"
ALPINE_APK_OPT: ""
AZURE_WEBAPP_ZIP: "${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${APP_VERSION}.${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip"
AZURE_DEV_RESOURCE_GROUP: "edsdmsdevwu2rg0"
AZURE_STG_RESOURCE_GROUP: "edsDMSPpdWu2Rg0"
AZURE_DEV_APP_NAME: "devedsdmswu2-appservice02"
AZURE_STG_APP_NAME: "ppdedsdmswu2-appservice02"
UI_APP: "devedsdmswu2-appservice02"
STG_UI_APP: ppdedsdmswu2-appservice02
AZURE_DEV_REDIRECT_URL: "https://datamarketplace-dev.t-mobile.com"
AZURE_STG_REDIRECT_URL: "https://datamarketplace-stg.t-mobile.com"
AZURE_DEV_CLIENT_ID: ""
AZURE_STG_CLIENT_ID: ""
AZURE_DEV_TENANT_ID: ""
AZURE_STG_TENANT_ID: ""
AZURE_DEV_API_URL: "https://devedsdmswu2-appservice02.devedsmgtwu2-iase1.appserviceenvironment.net"
AZURE_STG_API_URL: "https://ppdedsdmswu2-appservice02.prdedsmgtwu2-iase1.appserviceenvironment.net"
AZURE_DEV_DEVOPS_PWD: "${AZURE_CLIENT_SEC_RELIC_VAULT}"
AZURE_STG_DEVOPS_PWD: "${AZURE_STG_CLIENT_SEC_RELIC_VAULT}"

## @Description Install npm packages

npm-install:
stage: install
image: node:16.19.0
artifacts:
paths:
- "."
script:
- npm install

## This folder is cached between builds

.dependencies_cache:
stage: cache
cache:
paths:
- node_modules/

## Build version for dev

build_dev:
stage: build_dev
NODE_VERSION: "16.19.0"
CI: "false"
CLIENT_ID: ''
SERVICE_APP: ''
UI_APP: ${AZURE_DEV_APP_NAME}
extends: .npm-build
rules:
- if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^sso/develop/
- if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature/
when: manual
- when: never
artifacts:
paths:
- "."
allow_failure: true
timeout: 1h

## Zip version for dev

zip-dev:
image: alpine:latest
stage: package
script:
- echo "[INFO] Creating zip version of build folder"
- apk add zip
- echo "[INFO] Zipping ${BUILD_ARTIFACTS} into ${AZURE_WEBAPP_ZIP}"
- cd node_modules
- zip -r ../${AZURE_WEBAPP_ZIP} ./* -x '.??*'
rules:
- if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^sso/develop/
- if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature/
needs:
- job: build_dev
artifacts:
paths:
- "."
allow_failure: true
timeout: 1h

azure-dev-deploy:
image: ubuntu:latest
stage: deploy
- touch .env.development
- echo "REACT_APP_API_URL=${REACT_APP_API_URL}" >> .env.development
- apt-get install -y zip
- zip -r ${AZURE_WEBAPP_ZIP} public src node_modules package.json package-lock.json .env.development
- curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
- az login --service-principal -u "$DEPLOY_REACT_APP_AZURE_CLIENT_ID" -p "$AZURE_CLIENT_SEC_RELIC_VAULT1" -t "$DEPLOY_REACT_APP_AZURE_TENANT_ID"
- az webapp deploy -g ${AZURE_DEV_RESOURCE_GROUP} -n ${AZURE_DEV_APP_NAME} --src-path ./${AZURE_WEBAPP_ZIP} --type zip
retry: 2
needs:
- job: zip-dev
environment:
name: dev/azure/edsdmsdevwu2rg0/webapp/azure_appservicename
url: https://
allow_failure: true
timeout: 1h

I try to deploy on azure cloud app service with Gitlab-ci.yaml , but deployment getting succeed but node modules are not getting created so app service is not up and run please if some one help that will be great

Thanks to All.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).